# Build multi APK no Cordova sem Crosswalk?

Tags: apache-cordova, crosswalk

Desde que tirei o Crosswalk do meu projeto, o Cordova só build uma APK. Mas preciso do meu aplicativo na arquitetura x86 e ARM.

Como fazer isso sem o Crosswalk? Ou seria a APK padrão do Cordova uma APK híbrida para ambas as arquiteturas?

ps **Tirei o Crosswalk porque adiciona 30mb à APK, o que elevou muito a taxa de desistação do app.**

ps2 **Não tenho interesse nos modos alternativos de Build do Crosswalk sem a runtime.**

Comment: Conseguiu resposta? Também quero remove o crosswalk, mas me embananei com essas versões.